Extracting sudo information across line breaks
I am trying to capture a set of text from sudo files across various Linux servers via a Bash script.
Some of the text is formatted as follows:
Cmnd_XXXX Alias = /path/to/command/ command, \
/path/to/command/2 command, \
/path/to/command/3 command, \
/path/to/command/4 command, \
/path/t/command/5 command

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to capture the entire list of commands and nothing else.
The closest I've come is using like grep -A 6 so it would capture that first line and the following 6 lines after, however the amount of commands tend to vary per server and file. So I am trying to figure out if there is way to tell Linux to grab everything after each of those backslashes up until the last command in the list.

I took a quick stab at it (using AWK only from your subject line), putting your text into a file (a couple of times) along with some other random text to filter out (representing the multiple sources in your question).
I threw the AWK script into a file for easy editing, but I'm sure it could be simplified into a one-liner.
cat ./example.txt | awk -f ./filter.awk

filter.awk:
BEGIN { p=0; }
{
    if ( substr($1,1,5) == "Cmnd_" )    p=3;
    if (substr($0,length($0),1)=="\\")  p=2;
    if ( p > 0 )
    {
        if ( p == 2 )  s = substr($0,1,length($0)-1);
        else           s = $0;
        printf "%s ",s;
        --p;
        if ( p == 0 ) printf "\n";
    }
}

I assumed you wanted to filter on "Cmnd_", and added that.
I was able to capture the line ending "" and output those lines, and had it keep the final non-continued line (command 5 above). You can adjust to meet your specific need.
Cmnd_XXXX Alias = /path/to/command/ command,  /path/to/command/2 command,  /path/to/command/3 command,  /path/to/command/4 command,  /path/t/command/5 command 


You don't need cat; Awk knows how to read files. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat

Very true, cat is not needed.
Personally, I end up scripting 99% of the time, and use awk within very deep pipe streams (dozens of commands) ... so one-offs aren't my usual use-case. My bad.

That wouldn't just print the block that starts with Cmnd_. Try adding another block starting with some other string to the input and it'd be printed too.

Here is a simple Awk script which prints lines which end with a backslash starting from the matching line.
awk -v search="Cmnd_" '
    $0 ~ search { p=1 }
    p
    !/\\$/ { p=0 }' file

We set p to 1 if we find the search expression, then print lines as long as p is nonzero. If a line doesn't end with a backslash, we set p back to zero (don't print).
Demo: https://ideone.com/u9fXAc
This simple tool just ignores lines before the match, even if they would end with a backslash. It's not much harder to collect all lines joined by backslash+newline into a single record, but this crude tool doesn't do that.

Using GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:
$ awk -v RS='[^\\\\]\n' '/^Cmnd_/{printf "%s", $0 RT}' file
Cmnd_XXXX Alias = /path/to/command/ command, \
/path/to/command/2 command, \
/path/to/command/3 command, \
/path/to/command/4 command, \
/path/to/command/4 command, \
/path/t/command/5 command


$ awk -v RS='[^\\\\]\n' -F'\\s*[\\\\]\n' '/^Cmnd_/{$1=$1; printf "%s", $0 RT}' file
Cmnd_XXXX Alias = /path/to/command/ command, /path/to/command/2 command, /path/to/command/3 command, /path/to/command/4 command, /path/t/command/5 command


Thank you for this. It works for what I need.

You're welcome. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for what to do next.

You can just use awk's range pattern to print from the line matching /^Cmnd_/ till the first following line(including itself) which is not trailing with the backslash /[^\\]$/
awk '/^Cmnd_/,/[^\\]$/' file

To merge related command lines into one
awk -F, '/^Cmnd_/,/[^\\]$/{ printf("%s%s", $1, NF>1?", ":RS) }' file
#Cmnd_XXXX Alias = /path/to/command/ command, /path/to/command/2 command, /path/to/command/3 command, /path/to/command/4 command, /path/t/command/5 command


This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed -n '/Cmnd_/{:a;$!{N;/\\$/ba};p}' file

Find a line containing Cmnd_ and append the next line and if that line ends in \ go again.
If the appended line does not end in \ then print the collection.

you could try something like this:
sed -r 's/(^Cmnd_.*=.*$)/\1/g; # try to match a line that begins with Cmnd_ and has =
       tmatch; # if previous command matched, goto match label
       d; # delete current line; restart with next line
       :line; # label 'line'
       N; # read next entry and append it to current one
       :match; # 'match' label 
       s/\\$//g; # try to suppress trailing '\'
       tline; # if suppress was successful, goto 'line' label
       s/\n//g # remove all '\n' (were kept during append process)
       ' yourfile

this gives:
Cmnd_XXXX Alias = /path/to/command/ command, /path/to/command/2 command, /path/to/command/3 command, /path/to/command/4 command, /path/t/command/5 command
Cmnd_XXXX Alias = /path/to/command/ command

with a text file with a command on many lines and another single lined
